# PHP + json encode + Datatables

Tags: php, json, datatable

I'm using a jquery plugin called DataTables, and it requires me to return a json string in order to render the table.

Currently, the outputted json looks like this (see the aaData array):

```
{"sEcho":0,"aaData":[[{"ID":"1","idPatient":"122342","idFacility":"3","idTreatment":"3"}]]}
```

I'm wondering if the { } braces should actually be in the aaData array. In fact, I think the braces are actually what's causing the JSON parse error.

The actual code that generates this is listed below. (`core->dbh` is a PDO handle)

```
<?php

require_once('core/Core.php');
$core = Core::get_instance();

        $sql = 'SELECT ID, idPatient, idFacility, idTreatment
                FROM Pathology WHERE idPatient = 122342';

        $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // bind parameters
        $stmt->execute();

        // prepare output for DataTables

        $data = array("sEcho" =>intval($_GET['sEcho']),
                      "aaData" =>array()
        );

        while($result = $stmt->fetchAll()) {

                $data['aaData'][] = $result;

        }

            echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Could someone please tell me how can I remove the curly braces, or if the JSON is improperly formatted in another way that could be causing the parse error?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The JSON is fine. You are encoding it with PHP via json_encode, that can't be the problem. My guess would be that by doing this `$data['aaData'][] = $result;` you are nesting twice (see the double brackets) your results and the plugin fails. Try this: `$data['aaData'] = $result;`

Comment: Yes, i think  so. Result is a array of rows.